# How to get value from a hidden_field_tag using data-id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I get the value of an `hidden_field_tag` with `data-id` attribute?

**html.erb**

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "data-id" => 'cart-total', "value" => "#{total}" %>
#=> <input type="hidden" name="{"data-id"=>"cart-total", "value=>"1"}" id="__data-id__cart-total___value___1__">
```

**JavaScript**

```
var cartTotal = $("[data-id=cart-total]").val();
console.log(cartTotal); // undefined
```

I do not know the correct way to write this with rails `hidden_field_tag`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/hidden_field_tag):

```
hidden_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {})
```

Erb:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :hidden, total, "data-id" => 'cart-total' %>
```

Js:

```
$("[data-id='cart-total']").val();
```

Comment: Thanks. You've got a typo. Remove the last comma ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your element is wrong in the output, there is a object in `name`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="{"data-id"=>"cart-total", "value=>"1"}" id="__data-id__cart-total___value___1__">
```

I think it should be look like this (*i don't use rails*):

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "hidden", total, "data-id" => "cart-total" %>
```

And then you should use at least a better selector for the base element or something:

```
var cartTotal = $("input[data-id=cart-total]").val();
```

Comment: Hi. I need the html.erb syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided a name to your `hidden_field_tag`

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :field_name, "value" => "#{total}", "data-id" => 'cart-total', %>
```

Access it using data-id like this

```
var cartTotal = $("[data-id='cart-total']").val();
```